# How to add the same class to all existing post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I need to put specific class to every existing post in my site. I just need to put `class= obejrzane`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your theme, you’ll find the post_class function in your single.php file or in the content template files. as an example, in the WordPress Twenty Twenty theme, you can find the `post_class()` function in the template_part/content.php file.

here is the code  `<article <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">`

as you want to add a custom class just pass your class name in post_class()  as a parameter

`<article <?php post_class('obejrzane'); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">`